# When JSON object parse via Java Socket as a string additional symbols are added to the beginning when reading from client-side

Tags: java, json, sockets

I tried to send JSON object from server-side(in java) via java TCP socket by using `PrintWriter`.

The problem is when I read it from client-side(in java) as a string it gives extra offset characters to me.

```
�{"data":[{"route":"koswatta","routeNumber":"163","IdNo":"1"},{"route":"Battaramulla","routeNumber":"163","IdNo":"2"}]}
```

Above I mentioned my response when I read in client side. "`�`" mark is additional one. In client side I trimmed string value.before trimmed I also got "" symbol before "`�`" too.

*Actually above mentioned "" symbol has square inside inverted commas.(I don't know how to type that inside stack overflow question)*

***How can I remove this?***
 I'm a beginner to Java.Also sorry about my English.

Server Code:

```
public class serverTCP {
    public serverTCP() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Socket socket;
        System.out.println(RadiusSearchAlgo.getObj().toString());
        //Get size of object, convert to bytes to use as header
        String j1String = RadiusSearchAlgo.getObj().toString();
        long j1Size = j1String.length();
        byte[] j1AsBytes = new 
        BigInteger(Long.toString(j1Size)).toByteArray();


        //Set up socket
        int port = 45000;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 25000");
        while(true)
        {

            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String number = br.readLine();
            String number2 = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("num1 : "+number);
            System.out.println("num2 : "+number2);
            System.out.println("Message received from client is "+number);
            //Multiplying the number by 2 and forming the return message
            String returnMessage;
            try
            {
                int numberInIntFormat = Integer.parseInt(number);
                int returnValue = numberInIntFormat*2;
                returnMessage = String.valueOf(returnValue) + "\n";
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                //Input was not a number. Sending proper message back to client.
                returnMessage = "Please send a proper number\n";
            }

            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            bw.write(returnMessage);

            System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+returnMessage);
            bw.flush();


            //sending JSON Object
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(out);
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);

            PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(out, true);
            dout.write(j1AsBytes);
            pout.println(j1String+"\n");

            socket.close();

        }
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
public class Client_TCP {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {

    String ip = "localhost";
    int port = 45000; // 0-1023 :Reserved , 1024 to 65535 Can use. (this is server port number) one server can have multiple process/applications.so go to a specific process we use ports numbers.

    Socket socket = new Socket(ip,port);
    String str = "7";
    String string = "8";

    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter= new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
    OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

    printWriter.println(str);
    printWriter.println(string);

    outputStreamWriter.flush();


    //Get the return message from the server
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String message = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message+"\n");

    String ms2 = br.readLine().trim();
    System.out.println(ms2);

    outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
}
```

- RadiusSearchAlgo.getObj() is return my JSON Object.
- Server Code written in Java EE.
- Client Code written in Java SE.

Comment: Showing code would be smart. That's kind of always the case no matter what your problem is when coding.

Comment: Please include the code in your post than only we can debug the issue

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: I am using tomcat 8.5.201 server.I don't know how to find default character encoding method.

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `dout.write(j1AsBytes);`?

Comment: @Henry sorry.my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'garbage' consists of the byte contents of `j1AsBytes`, which you are sending, but not reading separately. If you don't need it, don't send it.